# What is the 2nd class value in terms of functional programming?

Tags: functional-programming

In functional programming,
1st class value is known as shown below:

- A value which can be assigned to a variable.
- A value which can be passed to a function as an argument.
- A value which can be returned from a function.

But I cannot find any definition about 2nd class value or 3rd, 4th, 5th..
I believe if something 1st exists then there must exist 2nd and 3rd...

What is the 2nd class value?

Could I find some examples of those values?

(If there is no 2nd class value, what about business class value?)

Generally, 1st class passengers are treated with higher priority.

Are 1st class values treated with higher priority? If so by the compiler or run-time?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The 2nd class values are all the others. By 1st class value they mean something like "materialized", "fully usable", "introspectable", just like any dead simple value at runtime.

Comment: By the way, that not only applies to functional programming. For example, in you typical scripting language, for example python, pretty much everything is a first class value: functions, classes, modules or to some extent every actual bytecode instruction

Comment: Thank you very much I understood..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps you are too picky.

First class values are those which have all the properties of values (so functions are first class because you can do about the same things on functions than on integers: pass them as arguments, store them in fields, etc...).

Some languages have some features which are not first class. For example, in Ocaml3 (but not today's Ocaml4) modules existed but could not be used as values (you could not pass a module as argument). At that time, modules were not first class values (and you could *informally* say that modules are second class!)

I never heard of 3rd class etc...

BTW, in many languages, even functional ones, the call stack is *not* a first class value (you often cannot inspect it, e.g. ask for the caller of the caller). Even Scheme which reifies continuations (with `call/cc`) does not enable inspection of the call stack (but some implementations provide this as an extension). And inspecting the closed values inside a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29) is often not possible....

"First class" should be read informally as a single adjective (there is no "cardinal set" of "classes" in that sense)

<sup>NB: I am not a native English speaker, so I cannot understand all English language subtleties</sup>

Comment: Your explanation is understandable for me. Thank you. But I think the naming is very much confusing. I think 'complete' value or 'good' value would be easier..

Comment: @Journeyer Think of "first class" as "not second class". There isn't anything more to it.

Comment: @Journeyer: I am *not* a *native* English speaker, so they are English language subtleties that I don't understand.

Comment: @JoSo O.K. I see. So there are '1st' and 'not 1st'. Thank you.. I'd seriously like to suggest change this term into somewhat easier.. if I can..

Comment: It is a decade-long (at least) habit to speak of "first class" things, so you won't be able to change the terminology. You'll need to adapt to the existing practice!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch O.K. Though you are not the native English speaker, your explanation is clear to me. Thank you.. I am also not the native speaker so we are 1st class non-native english speakers.. ^^;